# JPA - Duplicate records

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I am getting duplicate records.

I have two tables `Customer`, `Address`

In Customer.java

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "customer", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "customer_id" }) })
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
    @NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c")
    public class Customer implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private long customerId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Column(nullable = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Address> addresses;
```

In Address.java

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "address", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "account_id" }) })
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
    public class Address implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "account_id")
    private long accountId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Customer customer;
```

And Tables are:
Customer table:

```
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `customer_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `encrypt_key` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `theme_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `self_description` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customer_id`),
  KEY `idx_last_name` (`last_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=101 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Address table:

```
CREATE TABLE `address` (
  `account_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `address_type` varchar(15) NOT NULL,  -- Office, Branch-1, Branch-2, 
  `door_num` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `landmark` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `street` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `area_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `district` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `postal_code` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone1` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `phone2` varchar(20),
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`account_id`),
  KEY `idx_fk_city` (`city`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_id` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`customer_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=201 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Getting duplicate records:

```
{
  "customerId": 101,
  "active": 1,
  "email": "bbb@gmail.com",
  "encryptKey": "wwwwwfsad",
  "firstName": "aaa",
  "lastName": "bbb",
  "password": "user1",
  "selfDescription": "user1",
  "userName": "user1",
  "addresses": [
    {
      "accountId": 201,
      "addressType": "main office",
      "areaName": "area1",
      "city": "city1",
      "district": "district1",
      "doorNum": "89",
      "landmark": "landmark1",
      "phone1": "646432365465",
      "phone2": "4534542355675",
      "postalCode": "453245",
      "street": "street1"
    },
    {
      "accountId": 201,
      "addressType": "main office",
      "areaName": "area1",
      "city": "city1",
      "district": "district1",
      "doorNum": "89",
      "landmark": "landmark1",
      "phone1": "646432365465",
      "phone2": "4534542355675",
      "postalCode": "453245",
      "street": "street1"
    },
    {
      "accountId": 202,
      "addressType": "main office",
      "areaName": "area2",
      "city": "city2",
      "district": "district2",
      "doorNum": "89",
      "landmark": "landmark2",
      "phone1": "453454675",
      "phone2": "53425324",
      "postalCode": "7457646432",
      "street": "street2"
    },
    {
      "accountId": 202,
      "addressType": "main office",
      "areaName": "area2",
      "city": "city2",
      "district": "district2",
      "doorNum": "89",
      "landmark": "landmark2",
      "phone1": "453454675",
      "phone2": "53425324",
      "postalCode": "7457646432",
      "street": "street2"
    }
  ],
  "customerOptions": [
    {
      "id": {
        "questionId": 501,
        "customerId": 101,
        "optionId": 601
      }
    },
    {
      "id": {
        "questionId": 502,
        "customerId": 101,
        "optionId": 603
      }
    },
    {
      "id": {
        "questionId": 501,
        "customerId": 101,
        "optionId": 601
      }
    },
    {
      "id": {
        "questionId": 502,
        "customerId": 101,
        "optionId": 603
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How did you save the entities? Can you add the code ?

Comment: I inserted sample data in mysql workbench.

Comment: Can you describe what is the desired behavior? You indicate that you are getting duplicate records, but why do you expect to have only distinct records? How do you insert and read data from database?

Comment: show us the code how you are saving the entities?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is very simple but I found after a long fight. That is:

I converted all List fields to Set fields in all entity classes.

Comment: This is a workaround since the query already fetched duplicated data but the set denied it